# java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.io.FilePermission

Tags: java, security, file-io, file-permissions, accesscontrolexception

```
final File parentDir = new File("S:\\PDSPopulatingProgram");
parentDir.mkdir();
final String hash = "popupateData";
final String fileName = hash + ".txt";
final File file = new File(parentDir, fileName);
file.createNewFile(); // Creates file PDSPopulatingProgram/popupateData.txt
```

I am trying to create a file in a folder but I am getting exception as

```
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied
```

I am working in windows environment.  I can create a folder from the Windows Explorer, but not from the Java Code.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permission to create a file on that network share.  Can you create a file in that directory from within Windows Explorer or the command line?

Comment: Yes I can create a folder from the Windows Explorer, but not from the Java Code. Don't know why? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the Java app being launched? Is it running with the same privileges as your desktop session?

Comment: I am running the java code from my eclipse, and its workspace is setup in D drive.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: can you write to other drives using the Java code?

Comment: It is throwing exception at `parentDir.mkdir();`

Comment: No I cannot write to any other drive also.

Comment: Guys, this is a `java.security` exception. It has nothing to do with operating system permissions. It has to do with permissions enforced by the Java Security Manager.

Answer (score 27):

Within your `<jre location>\lib\security\java.policy` try adding:

`grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};`

And see if it allows you. If so, you will have to add more granular permissions.

See:

[Java 8 Documentation for java.policy files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

and

[http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html](http://archive.is/uN0K9)

Comment: That was it in my case!

Answer (score 9):

Although it is not recommended, but if you really want to let your web application access a folder outside its deployment directory. You need to add following permission in `java.policy` file (path is as in the reply of Petey B)

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "your folder path", "write"
```

In your case it would be

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "S:/PDSPopulatingProgram/-", "write"
```

Here `/-` means any files or sub-folders inside this folder.

**Warning:** But by doing this, you are inviting some security risk.

Comment: Special thanks for mentioning "/-". On windows, it will not work with backslashes in paths (like "\-"), and I assumed the wildcard operator would be "*", which led me straight into configuration hell...

Comment: In my case, the `java.policy` file is inside the properties folder under the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just document it here
on Windows you need to escape the `\` character:

```
"e:\\directory\\-"
```

Comment: From the [Oracle docs on policy files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html):
In order to assist in platform-independent policy files, you can also use the special notation of "${/}", which is a shortcut for "${file.separator}". This allows things like
    `permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.home}${/}*", "read";`