# Tomcat startup with security manager - CentOS

Tags: java, security, tomcat, centos

I've seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454037/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-io-filepermission) before, and the solution given works.

However, it doesn't fit in my needs, since it's granting read access to every directory, by setting this catalina.policy:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

So, my question is: There's some way to identify what file or resource is being requested but is denied when I take this grant off?

Here's the log that may be helpful, and appears when given Grant is removed:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.security.SecurityPermission getProperty.package.definition)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
>       at java.security.Security.getProperty(Security.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityConfig.setSecurityProperty(SecurityConfig.java:117)
>       at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityConfig.setPackageDefinition(SecurityConfig.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.setSecurityProtection(Embedded.java:990)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.(Embedded.java:130)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.(Embedded.java:115)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.(Catalina.java:58)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:410)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Troubleshooting), that's part of Tomcat's documentation, which allowed me to debug Security Manager's blocking results.

The "export CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.security.debug=all" option, when invoked while starting Catalina, print out every single access attempt that Tomcat executes, and the result of this attempt.

Since there's a bunch of files loaded by the system and this log method generates very large files, I preferred not to log it, and started my VM manually, printing the output in my screen.

I ran my JVM in command line like this:

```
/usr/local/java/jdk6/bin/java -server 
-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xms30m -Xmx1024m 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/var/tomcat/7.0/endorsed 
-classpath :/var/tomcat/7.0/bin/bootstrap.jar 
-Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy==/var/tomcat/7.0/conf/catalina.policy 
-Dcatalina.base=/var/tomcat/7.0 -Dcatalina.home=/var/tomcat/7.0 
-Djava.security.debug=all
-Djava.io.tmpdir=tmpdir org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap 
-config dir/to/xml.conf start
```